# Updating a custom field with Owner Id

Tags: apex, trigger

I had created a trigger a to update custom field with owner of that record.I written below query,the field is not getting updated.

```
trigger AssignedOs on Member_Referral__c (before insert) {

  if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        AssignedOsFunctionality.AssignOwnerToAssignedOs( Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class AssignedOsFunctionality{

    public static void AssignOwnerToAssignedOs(List<Member_Referral__c> listMemberRefs){
        for(Member_Referral__c mr : listMemberRefs) {
            system.debug('****** Owner ****'+mr.Owner);
            mr.Assigned_OS__c  = ''+mr.Owner;
        }
        //insert listMemberRefs;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mr.Assigned_OS__c = ''+mr.Owner;` should be `mr.Assigned_OS__c = mr.OwnerId;` and remove the if check as your trigger is in before

Answer (score 4):

Your trigger fires in the context `before insert`, but only calls the class if the trigger context `isAfter`, which will never be the case. Either change the if statement, or remove it entirely.

Comment: +1 You should have addressed the `Owner` versus `OwnerId`, though.

Comment: D'oh! That's what I get for trying to answer questions before I've been properly caffeinated...